# While uploading Application to Apple store I have got this Error?

Tags: ios

Hi While I am trying to upload application it gives me this errors Please help me in this task.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) also add armv6 to your build architectures:
[image]

2) Build it NOT with your Development Provisioning File. Build it instead with the Distribution Provisioning File. See screenshot and choose there iPhone Distribution under the point "Release".

[image]